# Python: How to dynamically put a loop around a function call?

Tags: python, function, loops, if-statement, continue

I have something to the effect of:

```
if condition:
    for variable in list:
        function_to_call(variable)
else:
    variable = "some value"
    function_to_call(variable)
```

This would probably work perfectly well if I didn't have some break and continue statements inside my function... 
As a result, I get the following error: `SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop` because although there is in fact a loop around the function (for which I'm checking with some variable - so the continue doesn't get executed when there is no loop around the function). It still doesn't work. 
I also tried putting the continue and break statement as a string inside an `exec()`, to no avail (same error).

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us what `function_to_call` looks like?

Comment: Are you trying to use `break` from within the function? Because you can't do that.

Comment: @Tomothy32 It's actually pretty complex - do you want to know something specific?

Comment: Why not put the for loop in the function and make the parameter a list instead of a variable? That way you can call function_to_call(list) in case #1 and call function_to_call( list of size 1 - the variable ) for case #2?

Comment: `function_to_call(list if condition else ["some value"])`, then fix `function_to_call` so that it *always* takes a list of values.

Comment: Or, `for variable in (list if condition else ["some value"]): function_to_call(variable)`.

Comment: @Micheal Kolber yeah, that's what I'm trying to do - I thought this would work, since I've got a loop around the function call

Comment: A function is not inlined as-is where you call it, so it can not modify the control flow of the loop you are calling it from. Instead, you might want to return a different value depending on the result of the functon. Then, the caller can check the return value and use that to control the loop.

Comment: @chepner Okay, thank you - I'm gonna try that right now

Answer (score 1):

Another solution not yet mentioned in the comments is to have the function return `False` instead of `break`ing. That way, you can ignore the return value when convenient, and use it otherwise.

You can then modify your code to look something like this:

```py
if condition:
    for variable in list:
        if not function_to_call(variable):
            break
else:
    variable = "some value"
    function_to_call(variable)
```

However, this may come with a drop in efficiency since you're checking the result in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: This is especially useful in cases where you can write functions representing specific conditions, like `is_quit_command` in a program that processes a list of commands. Also, depending on the particular use case, it might make more sense for the function to raise an exception that the caller can catch.

Comment: @jirassimok Raising an exception is actually the most efficient, as, if I recall correctly, there is no overhead involved in catching exceptions.

Comment: There's no overhead in using `try`/`except` as long as no exception is raised, so there's no reason to hesitate to use them for exceptional cases, but they aren't ideal for conditions that are expected to take on both values.